# getStaticProps params undefined despite being as expected in getStaticPaths - Next.js

Tags: next.js, strapi

completely new to Next.js & Strapi and following a tutorial but have been pulling my hair out over this part for a while.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/events?populate=*`);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data. Status: ${res.status}`);
    }

    const eventsData = await res.json();
    const events = eventsData.data;

    const paths = events.map((evt) => {
      const slugValue = `${evt.attributes.slug}`;
      console.log('Generated path with slug:', slugValue);
      return {
        params: { slug: slugValue },
      };
    });

    return {
      paths,
      fallback: true,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);

    return {
      paths: [],
      fallback: true,
    };
  }
}
```

The logged value of `slugValue` is returning a slug as expected (type string).

But when I log `slug` in getStaticProps below, I continually get `undefined`:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  try {
    console.log('Value of slug:', slug);

    const res = await fetch(
      `${API_URL}/api/events?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}&populate=*`
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data. Status: ${res.status}`);
    }

    const eventsData = await res.json();
    const events = eventsData.data;

    if (!events || events.length === 0) {
      return {
        notFound: true,
      };
    }

    return {
      props: {
        evt: events[0],
      },
      revalidate: 1,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);

    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong? Everything looks as expected in getStaticPaths with events returning an array of objects as expected and when I hit the url (in getStaticProps) I'm seeing the response I expect for the specified slug.

FYI: An an object from the events array looks like so:

```json
  {
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
      name: 'Throwback Thursdays with DJ Manny Duke',
      slug: 'throwback-thursdays-with-dj-manny-duke',
      venue: 'Horizon Club',
      address: '919 3rd Ave New York, New York(NY), 10022',
      date: '2024-08-21T18:00:00.000Z',
      time: '10:00PM',
      performers: 'DJ Manny Duke',
      description: [Array],
      createdAt: '2024-03-01T21:57:10.809Z',
      updatedAt: '2024-03-01T23:47:34.556Z',
      publishedAt: '2024-03-01T23:35:26.157Z',
      image: [Object]
    }
  }
```

Any idea why?

Comment: try using `context` instead of `params: { slug }` 
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props#when-should-i-use-getstaticprops